# How to iterate over rows of a Frame in DataTable

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datatable

With pandas I usually iterate the rows of a DataFrame with `itertuples` or `iterrows`. How can I do this kind of iteration on a Frame from Python DataTable?

Exemple of Pandas iteration that I need:

```py
for row in df_.itertuples():
    print(row)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.to_tuples` to achieve row iteration.

```
from datatable import dt
data = {"A": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
        "B": [4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
        "C": [7, 8, 9, 10, 11],
        "D": [5, 7, 2, 9, -1]}

DT = dt.Frame(data)

for row in DT.to_tuples():
        print(row)
```

Comment: The point to note is, with the above code one is NOT performing row iteration over a Frame! One would be working with regular Python tuples!

Answer (score 3):

From the [documentation for DataTables](https://datatable.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/frame.html):

> A Frame is column-oriented in the sense that internally the data is stored separately for each column. Each column has its own name and type. Types may be different for different columns but cannot vary within each column.

That being said, you can iterate over rows as:

```py
from datatable import dt, f, by, g, join, sort, update, ifelse

data = {"A": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
        "B": [4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
        "C": [7, 8, 9, 10, 11],
        "D": [5, 7, 2, 9, -1]}

# datatable
DT = dt.Frame(data)

# select single row
print(DT[2, :])

# Select several rows by their indices
print(DT[[2,3,4], :])

# Select a slice of rows by position
print(DT[2:5, :])

# Select rows on multiple conditions, using OR
print(DT[(f.A>3) | (f.B<5), :])
```

---

For more row iteration examples and comparison with Pandas DataFrame, have a look at [this official page](https://datatable.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual/comparison_with_pandas.html). In case you have some issues, you may raise the issue over at [DataTable official github repo](https://github.com/h2oai/datatable).

Comment: All right, so there is no built-in function on DataTable to iterate the rows of a frame? The correct way is using the index of a `for` loop?

Comment: Atleast the docs didn't mention one! Apparently they have focused on column level manipulations only!